# How not to dispose Stateful widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, dispose

I have an app. Its homepage has a lot of functionality(heaver). It takes a little bit time to build. Therefore when App starts I show the Splash screen in the meantime Homepage is built. But when I navigate(by push replacement) from the homepage to another it's dispose method called. So when I try to come back to the homepage it takes some time and the app got hang for that time. So I want that When I navigate(by push replacement) from Homepage to another page its dispose method should not be called. So, when user want to come back to the homepage it doesn't rebuild.

**Note:** I can not use Navigator.push or something else except push replacement because I am navigating from navigation bar( I made my custom Navigation Bar Where I cannot use anything else except push replacement).

Comment: Try Navigator.pop will not dispose widgets

Comment: I dont understand, how push is not possible, but surely it works with navigation bar, 
another solution might be, u can save all the info that u are getting from network to your cache, and so when it comes to your initial page, take data from cache, when app first time opens let it fetch data from network

Comment: I am using navigator.of(context).pushReplacement . So, I cannot use Navigator.pop . And I using it in navigation bar. Where there are many items so I cannot use anything else

Comment: If you want to persist you home route widget, you should not replace it when pushing a new route. If I understand right you don't want to allow the user to push many routes to the navigation stack but only one "above" home. So you could use `push` only when user is on the home page, `pushReplacement` in other cases, and `pop` if user navigates to home from another screen.

Comment: Peter koltai, I already used that workaround and it worked but actually I want to know, that is there any method in flutter from which we can control the call of dispose.

Comment: @zilaid I don't think it makes sense to prevent calling `dispose` when you literally are disposing the whole page with `pushReplacement` ...